# Download a file using Watir (Selenium) gem with Browserless chrome (docker chrome instance)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use browserless chrome docker instance to create a headless instance of chrome and download some files. So far using Watir integration on ruby it's very straight forward, but when I use the browserless instance I can't change the download directory. If anyone has any idea what could be wrong, it will be appreciated.

```rb
chrome_url = 'http://localhost:3000'
@download_directory = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp"
prefs = {
   'download' => {
      'default_directory' => @download_directory,
      'prompt_for_download' => false,
      'directory_upgrade' => true,
   },
}

args = [ '--headless', '--no-sandbox']

@browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, options: {prefs: prefs, args: args}, url: "#{chrome_url}/webdriver")

@browser.goto "https://www.dwsamplefiles.com/?dl_id=176"
```

To run the browserless chrome instance with:

```bash
docker run -p 3000:3000 browserless/chrome:latest
```